# How to parsing and aggregating the log into dataframe (3 lines to 1 line)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
Month  Date Time        Log                                                                                      Command    
Apr    4    20:30:33    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: --- got query from 10.10.10.243:30648:                Query
Apr    4    20:30:33    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: id:78b1 rd:1 tc:0 aa:0 qr:0 ra:0 QUERY 'no error'     Not Command
Apr    4    20:30:33    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: question: home.twitter.com:a:IN                       Not Command
Apr    4    20:30:34    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: --- sending udp query to 200.10.10.10:53              Sending
Apr    4    20:30:34    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: id:99a1 rd:1 tc:0 aa:0 qr:0 ra:0 QUERY 'no error'     Not Command
Apr    4    20:30:34    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: question: home.twitter.com:a:IN                       Not Command
```

In this dataset, I want to make every 3 lines to lines but actually I want to make it one row, the constraint is always 3 line into 1 line and yes the command is the first line from the 3 line, because I need to make for machine learning purpose

Below the expected result:

```
Month  Date  Time        Command        IP1                    IP2                           user      id      url                 message        
Apr    4     20:30:33    Query          200.200.200.254        10.10.10.243:30648            person    78b1    home.twitter.com    no error
Apr    4     20:30:34    Sending        200.200.200.254        200.10.10.53                  person    99a1    home.twitter.com    no error
```

Comment: What are the constraints for compressing the rows into one row. Like, how to extract IP1 & IP2? Also, would command be always the first Command?

Comment: Because I need for machine learning @hacker315

Comment: the constraint is always 3 line into 1 line and yes the command is the first line from the 3 line @hacker315

Comment: From what I can see, the first line out of every three lines contains all the information you need. Drop the 2nd and 3rd lines and then parse the first line of every group of three. Isn't that right?

Comment: Reset the index and then df[df.index % 3 == 0]?

Comment: @Spinor8 Yes it is

Comment: @run-out yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex. Hope I didn't make too many assumptions with your data

```
df

Month   Date        Time                                                 Log     Command
  Apr      4    20:30:33    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: --- got que...   Query
  Apr      4    20:30:33    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: id:78b1 rd:...   Not Command
  Apr      4    20:30:33    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: question: h...   Not Command
  Apr      4    20:30:34    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: --- sending...   Sending
  Apr      4    20:30:34    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: id:99a1 rd:...   Not Command
  Apr      4    20:30:34    200.200.200.254 dns,packet person: question: h...   Not Command

data = df.reset_index()
data.columns = ["month_name"] + list(data.columns)[1:]

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df = data[data.index % 3 == 0]

new_df['IP2'] = data[data.index % 3 == 0].Log.str.extract(r'(\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*:\d*)?:*$').values

new_df['IP1'] = data[data.index % 3 == 0].Log.str.extract(r'(\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*)\s').values

new_df['user'] = data[data.index % 3 == 1].Log.str.extract(r'(\w*):\s-*').values

new_df['id'] = data[data.index % 3 == 1].Log.str.extract(r'id:(\w*)\s').values

new_df['message'] = data[data.index % 3 == 1].Log.str.extract(r"'(\w*\s*\w*)'").values

new_df['url'] = data[data.index % 3 == 2].Log.str.extract(r'question:\s*(\w*.+):\w*:').values

new_df = new_df.drop(columns=["Log"]).set_index("month_name", drop=True)
new_df.columns.name = "Month"
new_df.index.name = None
new_df

Month   Date        Time    Command           IP2                  IP1        user  id      message           url
Apr        4    20:30:33    Query      10.10.10.243:30648   200.200.200.254 person  78b1    no error    home.twitter.com
Apr        4    20:30:34    Sending    200.10.10.10:53      200.200.200.254 person  99a1    no error    home.twitter.com
```